# Is PageCache utilization controlled by cgroup memory quota?

Tags: cgroups

If I create a cgroup with 100GB memory quota on a 256GB memory machine. After allocating 60GB anonymous memory in this cgroup, how much memory could be used for pagecache? 40GB or 196GB?